# Magento2 Authorize.net

Tags: magento2, authorize.net

In M1 we have the option for Authorize.net or Authorize.net Direct Post, in the site I am migrating we use the former.

In M2 this option is missing, how would I go about getting it back?

What is the difference and why is the former no longer there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Magento 1, the Authorize.Net method implements Authorize.Net AIM, with an inline credit card form that talks to the API through your server. Direct Post sends the data straight to Authorize.Net and then redirects back to your site.

In Magento 2, the only option available is Direct Post. They did this because it's more secure than the old AIM method--this way credit card data doesn't touch your server.

Authorize.Net Direct Post uses the same accounts and there are no extra fees, the interface is just a little different. You should be able to switch to it without any extra setup or issues, just enter your API keys.

If you don't want Direct Post, you can search for a third-party Authorize.Net extension for M2. There are several out there.